# How to do return a variable without breaking a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I was wondering how you can do `return()` in a loop without breaking the loop? i am making a stop watch and trying to return a variable but seems not to work;

My code:

```
def stopwatch():
  for i in range(10):
    return(i+1)
  
x = stopwatch()
print(x)
```

and my output is: `1`

how do i fix my code?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? A list of all numbers to be returned? Or each number to be printed?

Comment: i want it to print up to 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a generator?

```
def stopwatch():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i + 1
```

you can either get the "return" of a generator step by step with:

```
x1 = stopwatch()
next(x1)
# Out: 1
next(x1)
# Out: 2
# etc...
```

Or by looping over it again (even though I don't see any advantage of this compared to looping over a simple list):

```
x2 = stopwatch()
for num in x2:
     print(num)
```